# Proving function is convex

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

How do you show that $c + max(0,1-x)^{2}$ is convex where $c$ is a constant? I can graph it and observe that the function is below any line segment between any two points but I am not sure how to state it formally. Do I have to use Jensen's Inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way is to note that $f(x) = \begin{cases} c+(1-x)^2 & x < 1 \\
c & x \ge 1 \end{cases}$ and it is differentiable everywhere, with derivative $f'(x) = \min(2x-2,0)$. Since $f'$ is non-decreasing, $f$ is convex.

**Addendum**: Note that this characterization can be used, with appropriate modifications, on any convex function. This is because convexity is essentially a 'one dimensional' property.

To clarify, suppose $f:C \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function on a convex set $C$, then $f$ is convex **iff** for any $x_1,x_2 \in C$, the function $\phi: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$,  $\phi(t) = f(x_1+t(x_2-x_1))$ is convex.

Hence if the function $f$ is differentiable, then $f$ is convex iff for any $x_1,x_2 \in C$, $\phi'$ (defined above) is non-decreasing on $(0,1)$.

Comment: So if the derivative is non decreasing then the function is convex?

Comment: Correct. (Is is easy to see if the function is twice differentiable, then the second derivative is non-negative.)

Comment: Does this work for multidimensional functions?

Comment: @phil12: I added a note to the answer to that effect.